# SublimeText. Как поставить множественный курсор в результатах поиска?

Tags: поиск, sublime-text-3, курсор

Имеется XML файл такого вида:

```
<programmer>
  <id></id>
  <name></name>
  <gender></gender>
  <dob></dob>
  <status></status>
  <windows></windows>
  <linux></linux>
  <mac></mac>
  <other></other>
  <hourRate></hourRate>
  <expYears></expYears>
  <photo></photo>
</programmer>
```

В сроке поиска ввожу **><**
           Таким образом нахожу в файле все места смыкания тегов.
            Дальше требуется поставить множественный активный курсор между всех этих тегов, вот так **>|<**, чтобы потом разом вставить заготовленный текст, различный для каждого тега. Это возможно когда количество вставляемых строк совпадает с количеством активных курсоров, текст распределяется по порядку, то есть, первая строка - на место первого курсора и т.д.

Comment: А зачем? Вы ведь можете сделать замену сразу.

Comment: Я имею ввиду, мне просто нужно поставить туда активный курсор, чтобы потом печатать одновременно внутри всех тегов. Заменой курсор не поставить, можно только вставить символ.

Comment: Ну так вы можете заменить `><` на `>ваш_текст<` и это будет то же самое

Comment: Дело в том, что я для примера сказал, что мне нужно писать туда одинаковый текст, на самом деле - нужно вставлять одновременно и разный. Просто не хотел углубляться. Сейчас поправлю, чтобы не вводить в заблуждение.

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто, нужно было жать не 'Find', а 'Find All', и тогда все результаты выделяются и активный курсор мигает на каждом совпадении. Вопрос снят!